# how to convert ECMA-262(ActionScript3.0) RegularExpression to ICU(Objective-C) RegularExpression?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, ios, actionscript-3

Now, I something doing about parse work.

I want to use actionscript3.0 RegularExpression source code to Objective-C program.

**var reg:RegExp = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$", "gm");**

how to convert NSRegularExpression?

p.s: ActionScript 3.0 implements regular expressions as defined in the ECMAScript edition 3 language specification.

thk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how you use regexes in objective-c, reuse the pattern `^[0-9]+$` (btw. you can rewrite it to `^\d+$`). You need also to activate the modifiers `g` (global match ==> matches all occurences) and `m` (multiline, makes the `$` matches on line ends instead of string end).